# jQuery or Form -> PHP - not seeing post data or form data properly

Tags: php, jquery

I've tried serveral different ways to "pass data" from one site to another, and I'm not seeing it on the receiving site as I would expect.  Here are both attempts, and what I'm getting (if you are able to suggest a change I'll immediately try, and get back):

```html
 <a href="http://www.example.com/register" onclick="postdata()">1st Try</a>
<script> 
 function postdata(){

    $.post( "http://www.example.com/register", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
    alert("Done with Post");
}
 </script>
 
   <a onclick="formSend()">2nd Form Try</a>
  
 <script> 
 function formSend(){
 
        $('body').append('<form id="myawesomeform"></form>');
        $('#myawesomeform').attr('action','http://www.example.com/register');
        $('#myawesomeform').attr('method','post"');
        $('#myawesomeform').append('<input type="hidden" name="prev_id" id="prev_id" value="5">');
        $('#myawesomeform').append('<input type="hidden" name="next_id" id="next_id" value="45">')
        $('#myawesomeform').submit();
  }
</script>
```

Then in my php code, I have:

```
    echo('PAGE ROUTING: looking at post data received:  ');
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo('PAGE ROUTING: looking at get data received:  ');
    var_dump($_GET);
```

The 1st one shows:

```
   PAGE ROUTING: looking at post data received: array(0) { } PAGE ROUTING: looking at get data received: array(0)
```

and 2nd one, puts data in the query string, which I don't want, I want it hidden:

```
    http://www.example.com/register?prev_id=5&next_id=45

    PAGE ROUTING: looking at post data received: array(0) { } PAGE ROUTING: looking at get data received: array(2) { ["prev_id"]=> string(1) "5" ["next_id"]=> string(2) "45" }**
```

Comment: and the second one is GET because you got `"` at end of `post"`

Comment: first one is because it will follow the link.

Comment: yes @LawrenceCherone i agree that

Comment: I don't understand, regarding why it did not be a post

Comment: If I don' t put in the href, nothing happens.  It doesn't redirect.

Comment: because in HTML it would be interpreted as `post&quot;` rather than `post` and hence method used value is not determined as `POST`

Comment: I see, I didn't understand your comment at first.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt probably works fine, but you're immediately redirecting the user to a version of `/register` that did not have any POST or GET parameters. You need to prevent the browser from actually going to the URL in the `href` attribute:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/register" onclick="postdata(); return false">1st Try</a>
<script> 
    function postdata(){
        $.post( "http://www.example.com/register", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
        alert("Done with Post");
    }
</script>
```

If you look at the network inspector of your browser's developer tools, you should see that an XMLHttpRequest was performed in the background, with the response containing the data in the `$_POST` array.

The `return false` I added to `onclick` will tell the browser NOT to send the user to whatever URL is in the `href` attribute. Basically, it sends an "abort" signal.

Your second attempt is not working because you have a `"` character in the method-attribute:

```
$('#myawesomeform').attr('method','post"');
// right here: ------------------------^
```

If you change that to the following, it should work properly:

```
$('#myawesomeform').attr('method','post');
```

Comment: Thanks @rickdenhaan.  The form worked, adding the return false still did not work, but that's ok, as long as one does, unless you want me to  try something else there.

Comment: Can I ask: both of these run on the same server, is there a very easy way I could pass a changing number from one side to the other, so that no one can force their way in on the register, that you can think of.  Would it be a clock time maybe, and how might I code that?  Thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console with the first attempt? Do you get the `alert()`?

Comment: That should be a separate question.

Comment: I do get the alert, and I see no errors.  Do you want me to bring up the debubber, I'm in Chrome, I can try that.  or do you simply recommend a the form method anyway, is that fine?

Comment: Yes, by "console" I meant the one from Chrome's dev tools.

Comment: I'm going to use the form method, that seems simple and works.  Thanks